# How to create topics in websocket like stomp or another protocol golang

Tags: go, websocket

How to create topics and send websocket message in golang? I'm using the gorilla/websocket library to create my websocket but I wanted to create topics to send and receive messages, does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I'll leave my code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/gs-guide-websocket", wsHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("x.x.x.x:8080", nil))

    // Fecha a conexão

}

func wsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        messageType, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Received message:", string(message))

        err = conn.WriteMessage(messageType, message)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help, whoever can help

Comment: I just wanted to be able to send a message to a topic, the code above is just an example. Thanks!

Comment: "the code above is just an example" - unfortunately an example that works fine (as this code does; it will echo any messages it's sent) does not really help us understand your problem, so please add detail (maybe provide an example as to what messages you are expecting to send/receive). It would be helpful if you could define "topics" (the term is not used in the [websocket RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) so it's meaning here is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is not a message queue protocol, so there is no concept of "topics". It requires the client to actively request the server through the HTTP protocol, and then both sides negotiate to upgrade to a WebSocket connection. You can maintain this connection and then directly send any messages to the other party.

Comment: I understand, but can I connect to websocket and send messages to all connected users? Or do I need a stomp? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: You can manage multiple websocket connections yourself (see the [chat](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/main/examples/chat) example). Alternatively you can use an implementation of an existing PubSub protocol (options include MQTT, AMPQ, zeromq etc).

Comment: I'll take a look and then I'll give you feedback.

Comment: Should I use PubSub together with my websocket? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: That really depends upon your requirements. ["PubSub"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) is the term for a messaging pattern; there are many different/incompatible standards/implementations. If you are implementing a basic chat server then the chat example shows a way of doing this, protocols like STOMP/MQTT/AMPQ may help but each have their own use-cases (e.g. [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Overview) "arose from a need to connect to enterprise message brokers from scripting languages such as Ruby, Python and Perl.").

Comment: Stomp is out of date Can I still use it?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Stomp before. There are many protocols that can achieve similar functionality, you can also take a look at mqtt.js.

Comment: I'm now using mqtt with golang. Do you know any way to get the "Subscribe" in android jetpack compose?

Comment: @RafaelSouza you will probably have more luck if you ask that as a new question. I can help with Go MQTT questions (wrote a decent portion of the Paho libraries) but have no experience with Jetpack (and the tags you use when asking a question determines who is likely to see it).

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Can you send a message to a mqtt:

Server:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    mqtt "github.com/mochi-mqtt/server/v2"
    "github.com/mochi-mqtt/server/v2/hooks/auth"
    "github.com/mochi-mqtt/server/v2/listeners"
)

func main() {
    // Create signals channel to run server until interrupted
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-sigs
        done <- true
    }()

    opts := mqtt.Options{
        InlineClient: true,
    }
    // Create the new MQTT Server.
    server := mqtt.New(&opts)

    // Allow all connections.
    _ = server.AddHook(new(auth.AllowHook), nil)

    // Create a TCP listener on a standard port.
    tcp := listeners.NewTCP("t1", "0.0.0.0:1883", nil)
    err := server.AddListener(tcp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        err := server.Serve()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(time.Second * 5) {
            err := server.Publish("topic/test", []byte("Hello World!\n"), false, 0)
            if err != nil {
                server.Log.Error("server.Publish", "error", err)
            }
            server.Log.Info("main.go issued direct message to direct/publish")
        }
    }()

    // Run server until interrupted
    <-done

    // Cleanup
}
```

Client:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

// var messagePubHandler mqtt.MessageHandler = func(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
//  fmt.Printf("Received message: %s from topic: %s\n", msg.Payload(), msg.Topic())
// }

var connectHandler mqtt.OnConnectHandler = func(client mqtt.Client) {
    fmt.Println("Connected")
}

var connectLostHandler mqtt.ConnectionLostHandler = func(client mqtt.Client, err error) {
    fmt.Printf("Connect lost: %v", err)
}

func main() {
    var broker = "localhost"
    var port = 1883
    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://%s:%d", broker, port))
    //opts.SetClientID("go_mqtt_client")
    //opts.SetUsername("username")
    //opts.SetPassword("password")
    // opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(messagePubHandler)
    opts.OnConnect = connectHandler
    opts.OnConnectionLost = connectLostHandler
    client := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }

    sub(client)
    // Keep the server running
    select {}
    // publish(client)

    //client.Disconnect(250)
}

func publish(client mqtt.Client) {
    num := 10
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        text := fmt.Sprintf("Message %d", i)
        token := client.Publish("topic/test", 0, false, text)
        token.Wait()
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func sub(client mqtt.Client) {
    topic := "topic/test"
    token := client.Subscribe(topic, 1, func(c mqtt.Client, m mqtt.Message) {
        fmt.Printf("Mensagens: %s", m.Payload())
    })
    token.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Subscribed to topic: %s", topic)
}
```

Can you send a message to a stomp:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-stomp/stomp"
)

func main() {
    // Endereço do servidor STOMP
    serverAddress := "localhost:61613"

    // Conectar ao servidor STOMP
    conn, err := stomp.Dial("tcp", serverAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Disconnect()

    // Destino para enviar mensagens
    destination := "/topic/greetings"

    // Corpo da mensagem
    messageBody := "Hello, STOMP!"

    // Subscrever para receber mensagens
    sub, err := conn.Subscribe(destination, stomp.AckAuto)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }
    defer sub.Unsubscribe()

    // Enviar uma mensagem
    err = conn.Send(destination, "text/plain", []byte(messageBody), nil)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }

    // Aguardar por mensagens
    for {
        msg := <-sub.C
        fmt.Printf("Mensagem recebida: %s", msg.Body)
    }
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-stomp/stomp/server"
)



func main() {

    err := server.ListenAndServe("localhost:61613")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

ThanKs @nameless6849 and @Brits

Comment: This answers the question "How do I create a STOMP connection"; your question related to websockets and made no reference to STOMP (this answer does not create a websocket connection).

Comment: Sorry, I used websocket and stomp in springboot and now I'm migrating to golang

Comment: Then your question should state this; as things stand your question is unanswerable (this answer does not respond to the question you asked).

Comment: Ok, but do you know of any way to do this with websocket and stomp together? it would be even better thanks.

Comment: I'm going to make a websocket with stomp then edit the answer

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/go-stomp/stomp/issues/116#issuecomment-1066009859) for an example. You also really need to edit the question to specify that STOMP must be used (as mentioned there are many protocols that can be run over a Websocket connection).